# Get raw list from OrderedEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have an object which has a property that contains an IEnumerable of objects. Each object in the `IEnumerable` has a property that is also an `IEnumerable`. I am attempting to capture a larger list of the inner property. Unfortunately, the lambda expression that I am using is returning an `OrderedEnumerable`. I'd like to just retrieve a simple `IEnumerable`.

```
public class OrgForm
{
    public string OrgNum { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CustomerForm> CustomerFormList
    {
        get
        {
            var list = from cf in OrgCustomerList
                       where cf.Customer.AssignedOrg == OrgNum
                       select cf;

            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

**Use of `CustomerFormList`**

```
OrgForm of = new OrgForm();
IEnumerable<Machine> machines = of.CustomerFormList
                                  .Select(cf => cf.ActiveMachines);
```

**Edit**

So after prompting from Jon Skeet and Mark Byers I looked a little deeper and found that ActiveMachines had been modified to perform an `OrderBy` so now the return of an `OrderedEnumerable` makes sense (my bad for not reading code set change comments).

```
public class CustomerForm
{
    public IEnumerable<Machine> ActiveMachines
    {
        get
        {
            var active = Customer.MachineList.ToList()
                .Where(m => "a".Equals(m.MachineStatus)
                            && !m.ToReapp);

            return active.OrderBy(m => m.MachineCategory);
        }
    }
}
```

This is great except `machines` doesn't allow me to write something like this as it sees each item in `machines` as an enumerable based on the category.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string[]> kvp in trueUpPt)
{
    Machine machine = cf.ActiveMachines
        .First(m => m.MachineSk == kvp.Key);
    machine.MachineLicenseBillback.ProjectNum = kvp.Value[0];
    machine.MachineLicenseBillback.TaskNum = kvp.Value[1];
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work". Is at a compile-time error or an exception at run-time? What error message do you get?

Comment: I still don't understand your question, sorry. Perhaps you could try to simplify your problem so that the entire code including all necessary classes and functions fits on one screen, and make it so we can copy and paste the code into Visual Studio and see the exact same error that you see. There's too much code missing for me to guess what your problem could be.

Comment: I don't understand the edit. ActiveMachines explicitly returns an IEnumerable<Machine>, not an IEnumerable<IEnumearable<Machine>>. What do you mean by "doesn't allow me"? Like Mark originally said, be explicit about the error or bug you're seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OrderedEnumerable<T>` *is* an `IEnumerable<T>` - it's one particular implementation. Obviously you've got to return *some* implementation (or null) - it's not going to be an instance of the interface directly.

The code you've presented should be fine as it is. It's *declared* to return `IEnumerable<T>` so it shouldn't make any difference unless you cast the result. Having said that, the property you've shown shouldn't be returning an `OrderedEnumerable` anyway... Enumerable.Where just returns a new iterator. Admittedly it won't change the order so you *could* have an overload for `Where(this IOrderedEnumerable<T>)` but I don't believe there's one in the standard library.

What problem is this actually causing you, and are you using some extra libraries? If you could come up with a short but complete example it would really help.

Comment: I added my ultimate intent to the question. Thank you for the clarification on `OrderedEnumerable<T>`. Still learning lambda / linq and have to be weary of jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand "capture a larger list of the inner property" correctly, you just want

```
of.CustomerFormList
    .Where(cf => cf.Customer.AssignedOrg == OrgNum)
    .SelectMany(cf => cf.ActiveMachines)
```

That will return you an `IEnumerable<Machine>`. As mentioned by the other answers, `IOrderedEnumerable<T>` is just a subinterface of `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: +1 This looks like an intelligent guess of what he wants, based on the names of the fields. I don't see any "order by" in his code anyway so I'm still very confused about that part of his question...